# Conditional class based on async property in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have something like the following:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items | async" >
    <button [class.current]="currentItem == item">
      {{ item.whatever}}
    </button>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

The class `current` should only be set, if the `item` is equal to `currentItem`. `currentItem`, however is also loaded asynchronously from a data source (SQLite). Therefore, `currentItem` is null, when the view is first rendered.

What do I have to do, to make the view wait oder update when the `currentItem` is loaded?

Comment: how does asyncPropertyOrMethod() look like?

Comment: This is what I like to know. I load the current item using "normal" Promise based code from SQLite. Will edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: `let item of item` seems wrong. use something lik `let item of items` (make sure you receive data in `items`). what do you want to achieve that is not clear.

Comment: tell us which json object you get? and what you exactly want? `isCurrentItem(item)` should `return true`. if it returns true, button will have `current class` effect.

Comment: The items load without problem and I get the expected data (`BehaviorSubject<List<Item>>`) - just a typo there.

Comment: @micronyks - any better with the latest edit?

Comment: Which data `items` object contains? Show me that json object. you can get it by writing `{{items|json}}` somewhere in template.

Comment: When I try `{{items|json}}` the following error is thrown: `Converting circular structure to JSON`

However, `item` is a class with properties like `id`, `name` etc. and `currentItem` is an object of the same class.

Comment: Okay okay. You won't be able to do it as you are dealing with async.

Comment: is `currentItem` an object or a variable? & what about `item (each element of items)` (object or variable)?

Comment: `currentItem` is an object. Why is `item (each element of items)` better?

Still not sure I made clear what my problem is - but thank you for the discussion an help so far!

My problem is, that `currentItem` is not set when the page is rendered, because `currentItem` is loaded  async as well.

I therefore need a way to re-render the component when `currentItem` is loaded, make the rendering wait until `currentItem` is loaded or ...

Comment: if is an object, you must be looking for any property lik currentItem.something. right??? if so, tell me what something property is?

Comment: I would say `id` makes sense. But I can't use `currentItem.id == item.id`, because `currentItem` is `undefined` at render time.

Comment: Yes so use `?.` operator as `currentItem?.id == item.id`

Comment: That is a very nice operator - thanks. Found a way to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  **safe navigation operator (?.)** as shown below,

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items | async" >
    <button [class.current]="currentItem?.id == item.id">  //<----here
      {{ item.whatever}}
    </button>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```